# Spring-Integration: Execute poller trigger by last message from previous poll

Tags: spring-integration

I have poller configuration like this:

```
<int:poller id="myPoller" default="true"  max-messages-per-poll="2" task-executor="executor"
                error-channel="errorChannel" receive-timeout="20000" trigger="dynamicTrigger">
    </int:poller>
```

But i need to trigger the poller with last time message from previous poll. For example of the flow:

If i have 4(A,B,C,D) Post rest the app will process 2(A,B) message first and  then wait for the last response (either from A or B), afterward trigger the poll for next message (C,D).

How to achieve that condition ? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I suggest you to take a look into poller's `<advice-chain>`. With some custom `MethodInterceptor` you perform your decision logic and call your polling source `stop()`. When you have a desired response somewhere downstream you just perform `start()` of that endpoint again to let proceed with a new bunch of messages.

With enough big `polling-interval` you even don't need that `<advice-chain>` and just perform `stop()` in the downstream as well, via some state checking.

Also consider to use `Control Bus` for `stop/start` operations.

Comment: Thank you Artem. I'll try to use that